# Safari address bar shows a blank page with "data:," after posting a form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, safari, ckeditor, turbolinks

When I post a form to my rails website (using turbolinks, not sure if it is relevant) from safari on mac, instead of redirecting to the next page, it just shows a blank page, with "data:," in the address bar.

I have an embedded youtube video on the page, in case that is relevant. Also, my form has a textarea that uses ckeditor.

The record is saved, just that it does not redirect to the show page as I would expect.

This does not happen on chrome.

The page source for the blank page shows up as:

```
<html> = $0<head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have not left a debugging statement like `abort` somewhere in your application?

Comment: @max Yes, I double checked just now as well...